# I want to perform aggregation based upon an id value in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

data present is like:

```
ID         Tenor     Value   
ABC        10 years  10000
ABC        20 years  20000
ABC        25 years  30000
XYZ        2  years  12000
XYZ        5  years   8000
```

Output should be :

```
ID         Tenor     Value   
ABC        10 years  60000---->(30000+20000+10000)
ABC        20 years  50000---->(30000+20000)
ABC        25 years  30000
XYZ        2  years  20000---->(12000+8000)
XYZ        5  years   8000
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Edit your question and provide some more info...

Comment: You're going to need to explain your logic as well.

Comment: The logic is clear but not the data. Do you really have a column with the text "10 years"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tenor` is numeric

```
select  ID
       ,Tenor

       ,sum(Value) over
        (
            partition by    ID
            order by        Tenor
            rows            between current row
                            and     unbounded following 
        ) as Value

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------+-------+
| id  | tenor | value |
+-----+-------+-------+
| ABC |    10 | 60000 |
| ABC |    20 | 50000 |
| ABC |    25 | 30000 |
| XYZ |     2 | 20000 |
| XYZ |     5 |  8000 |
+-----+-------+-------+
```